# Let $x$ lie on the surface of a sphere centered at the origin. Prove that $(\tau /\kappa) + ( (1/\tau )(1/\kappa)' )' = 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, frenet-frame

So this problem is really confusing me.

Here is a hint we had: (Hint: since the Frenet frame is a frame, write $x = aT + bN + cB$ and work from there)

I had an initial idea based on the hint, but my teacher suggested a different method. He said he said he took derivatives of $(X\cdot X) $ and then used the frenet equations to solve for it.

This is something we worked through together and I completely understand these steps.

\begin{align} 
x\cdot x &= \text{constant}\\
\Rightarrow  x\cdot x' &= 0 \\
\Rightarrow x\cdot T &= 0\\
(x.T)' &= x'\cdot T + x\cdot T' \\
&= T\cdot T + x\cdot (\kappa N) \\
&= 1 + \kappa x\cdot N = 0\\
\Rightarrow x\cdot N = -1/\kappa
\end{align}
and then take more from there.

My question, is where do I go from there. In working this out we have something that equals $-1/\kappa$ (and the initial problem has $1/\kappa$). The problem also has a $t/\kappa$ which could just be $t$ times $1/\kappa$. So, would I do similar steps to get something in the form of $1/\kappa$ and then have what I need to solve the problem? Like we have done no examples of anything like this in my class, so I do not know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

We define $\alpha = \lambda T + \mu N + vB$ for some functions $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $v$.
Since $\alpha$ is orthogonal to the tangent vector, we get
$$\alpha = \mu N + vB$$
Now differentiate,
$$T = \alpha' = \mu' N + \mu(-kT + \tau B) + v'B -v\tau N$$
$$0 = \mu' N + \mu k T + \mu\tau B + v'B - v\tau N - T$$
$$0 = T(-\mu k - 1) + N( \mu' - v\tau) + B( \mu \tau + v')$$
Since $\{T,N,B\}$ are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, we should get 3 equations:
\begin{align}
-\mu k - 1 &= 0 \\
\mu' - v\tau &= 0 \\
\mu \tau + v' &= 0
\end{align}

Now,

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{k} = -\mu$$
$$\Rightarrow \mu' = v \tau$$
$$\Rightarrow \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)' = -\mu' = -v\tau$$
$$\Rightarrow v' = -\mu \tau$$
$$\Rightarrow  v = -\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)'\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right)$$
Differentiate $v$,
$$v' = -\bigg(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)'(\frac{1}{\tau})\bigg)'$$
$$v'=v'$$
$$-((\frac{1}{k})'(\frac{1}{\tau}))' = \frac{\tau}{k}$$
Finally we get,
$$\left(\frac{\tau}{k}\right) + ((\frac{1}{k})'(\frac{1}{\tau}))' = 0$$
as desired.